# Jtable loading too many registers in MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-jtable

I am loading a List of Users in MVC4 with jtable.

But as I have more than 5000 users, the table takes too long to load.

I would like to find a way to load just some pages and keep the jtable paging and the most important thing is to keep jtable search property.

Is there a way to do so using AJAX or somethng??

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[jtables paging](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/277576/AJAX-based-CRUD-tables-using-ASP-NET-MVC-and-jTa#Paging)

This site has some good documentation on using jtables and ajax paging. This should help with filtering as well.